# Can't make sense of the CSS loading order

Tags: theming, 8

I want `bootstrap.css` to load first, because it's breaking all of my styles.  Yet, no matter what settings I use in my module, it always loads last.  Every CSS file from a library in my theme loads last.  Using 'base' makes my bootstrap library load before my theme's other libraries, but yet after every other module and theme.  I see no differences between my theme and the core themes, yet core themes are loading first.

Even if I set weights on my CSS files with the `{ weight: <whatever> }` option, it doesn't make the libraries appear before any other theme or module.

I've even tried changing the core.extension config to change the order of the module, to both high and low numbers, in desperation.

All I want is for my theme's library to load first.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278774/theme-css-libraries-always-loaded-after-module-libraries